# Corner numbering

Tags: mathematics

Give numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 to free corners of the hexagons or prove it is not possible with the following conditions:

1. vertical corners A's must have the same number;
2. "neighboring" corners B's must    have the same number;
3. the order of numbering (for example, clockwise) for all  hexagons must be different.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the definition of "neighboring"?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, is the "corners B's for adjacent hexagons" more correct?

Comment: But then shouldn't the 6 and 1 in the same two hexagons be the same too?

Comment: No, I think, because two corners (before 1, 6, and after B, 6) in the same two hexagons must have different number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the rules properly it can be done easily.

> [image]

Notes about unicity

> Between the two hexagons on the right you need to fit twice the same digits.  These can only be 1 and 6.  The same applies to the bottom and bottom-left hexagons.
>   This means that these 4 hexagons plus the center have digits 1 and 6 adjacent.  On the other hand the top and top-left hexagons have digits 1 and 6 opposed.  This shows that the top and top-left hexagons cannot be identical to any of the other 5.  These also cannot be identical to each other because in the top hexagon 1 and A are adjacent, in the top-left they are not.
>  So by construction the top and top left hexagons are unique.
>
>  A similar argument shows that only the bottom and bottom-right hexagons have digits 4 and 3 in opposing position and are different from each other.
>
>   This leaves only 3 hexagons, bottom-left, center and top-right, that could be identical.  They all have 2 and 5 opposed.  The remaining pairs 1,6 and 3,4 can be put in 4 ways, and are only required to be different from each other.  This allows 3*2 = 12 ways.
>
>  So how many solutions are there?
>  Given the constraints, between each pair of border hexagons only 2 digits are possible.  These pairs can be put in 2 ways each giving 2^6 = 64 possible ways, ignoring unicity.
>  The unicity constraints needs to be checked only between the bottom-left, center and top-right hexagons.  Of the 4 ways for bottom-left 3 are different from the center, and of the 4 ways for top-right, 2 are different from bottom-left and center.  So out of the 64 ways, only 64 * 3/4 * 2/4 = 24 remain valid.

Comment: Is your solution unique? While six orientations are considered identical.

Comment: It is probably not unique.  I just filled in the blanks according to the constraints.  About twice I had to swap two digits to avoid a duplicate and that worked.  I even avoid duplicates if mirror images are considered identical.